# PHP - Get string based on file

Tags: php, string

simply in php we could replace a string by other string such as using a particular function, str_replace (), etc

suppose I have a `file.txt` contains

```
text1
text2
text3
...
text n
```

and i have a variable `$text` such as:

```
$text = "I want to get text1 and text2";
```

How to get the strings (text1 and text2) based on the available strings in file.txt?

i want to have a new variable say ($new) which contains strings of $text that it fits on the string file.txt

i appreciate your help greatly.

thank you

Comment: [`file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) reads a file into an array of lines. From there, you just need the first two array elements.

Comment: Hi @MichaelBerkowski sorry before, i want to have a new variable say ($new) which contains strings of $text that it fits on the string file.txt

Answer (score 2):

Use this:-

```
$lines = file('textfile.txt');

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    Do something....
}
```

Comment: can you give any clearly example using ur answer of my problem?

Comment: still confused, how to adjust two text..

Comment: What confusion do you have ?   To get text1 and text2 use $text= $lines[0] . $lines[1];